# How to read through an unordered_map while it is changing dynamically all the time

Tags: c++

For some reason, we have been using the *unordered_map* type to store objects in our project. In run time, the size of the map is always changing as it may drop objects or add new objects at any time. Now I need to traverse the objects of it one by one in another thread. You know I can't do this by using the iterator because it may go invalid when the map changed. So my question is how I can go through the unordered_map correctly in spite of the dynamic change.

Comment: Do you have to stick with unordered_map or is using other data structures a possibility? Also, do you have a single writer and multiple readers, or multiple writers and multiple readers?

Comment: No, I can not because it is widely used in our project in the first place. Neither do I have the authority nor I have the time as change may have a knock-on effect on a lot of things.

Comment: How are the threads that modify the unordered_map coordinating their accesses now?

Comment: Currently, this unordered_map is only accessed by a single thread. But I intend to traverse it in another thread.

Answer (score 3):

You need a mutex or other kind of lock and you need to make sure the collection is only accessed under protection of the mutex. Otherwise, accessing the collection in one thread while another thread is or might be modifying it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Good point.It is inevitable to keep the data consistent in this concurrent case.

Comment: What does the code do now? How does it modify the unordered_map while other thread might be accessing it? (Or does only one thread ever touch the unordered_map? Or what?)

Comment: Yes, it is accessed by only one thread in our current design.

Comment: Ahh, then you have two obvious choices: 1) Fundamentally change the design so the map can be accessed by more than one thread by making appropriate changes to all code that accesses the map. 2) Arrange so that your code is run in the thread that is allowed to access the map. (Or that thread makes a copy of the map and gives it to you, or something like that.) Changing a design from single-threaded to multi-threaded is not a trivial change, it's an architectural change. If you are going to make that kind of change to the map, expect it to affect all code that uses the map.

Comment: Absolutely, I think the second option makes more sense to me. Thanks for your comments. So nice of you.

Comment: I think you're probably right. Ultimately, it may be worth it to change the design so the map is locked and can easily be accessed by any thread. (Of course, I don't have enough information to know for sure.) But that doesn't sound like the "quick and local" fix you need right now. Just make sure you don't "bog down" an essential thread for too long and cause problems for the application as a whole. (You could cause those same problems by locking the map though -- the critical thread might block on the map lock anyway.)

Comment: yes, incorporating the reader thread(it does take heavy task) into the essential thread could cause the latter rather sluggish. That's what I worry about a lot.

Comment: But on the other side, even if you do it in a different thread, you'll still have to lock the map for as long as it takes you to do whatever it is you're doing. If the essential thread goes to access the map while you hold the lock, it'll be blocked until you finish anyway.

Comment: We have finalized the solution. First, I am going to do the traverse in the essential thread rather than in a separated thread. On the other hand, instead of accessing the unordered_map directly, I'm going to introduce a new linear structure, which will maintain all the indexes(just indexes) replicated from he unordered_map. The contents of the new container will change upon any change(add/drop)  occurred on the map. In this way, the traverse can be made trackable. We just need to traverse the indexes in the linear container and get the value against a particular index from the unordered_map

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for doesn't make sense.  What would it *mean* to traverse a changing collection when you can't define "current element"?  It may also happen that the element you just read out of the table gets deleted in another thread before you get the chance to use it.

Your best bet would be to rethink the design of whatever you're doing.

Comment: Assuming the code he's working on isn't nonsensical, it probably already has a solution to precisely this issue. (Unless the map is exclusively accessed by one thread right now, in which case changing that will require some design changes.)

Comment: yes, I know it sounds like a paradox but I have to achieve this anyway. I can not change the design as this may cause great effort and I don't have the authority at all.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to heavy use of locks is replication, which you might consider if:

1. This type of access from the second thread has to happen so frequently that locks would incur a very high runtime overhead.
2. The data doesn't have to necessarily be 100% up to date at a given moment in time from the reader's viewpoint.
3. Memory footprint is not a major concern for you.

Your reader thread could store its own copy of the data which would be updated only periodically, at known sync points. The reader thread could then access the data as many times as it desired without using locks, until the next time its data is refreshed from the writer thread's copy.

Comment: I'll rephrase without using that term. I wanted to get across the concept of representing one conceptual piece of data among multiple threads through replication.

Comment: Replication was one of the solutions I have thought over. As you stated, this solution is not good enough as it can not guarantee the data consistency.